# Why start selected the close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Im trying the Jquery Dialog **[Demo](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)**

But the dialog show the `X` selected and like a blue halo. When click outside is clear. But seem weird this start that way.

I copy the sample code in a separated HTML and same behaviour.

Any idea why that happen and if there is a workaround for it?

[image]

### SOURCE CODE

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm wondering if this is bug in a somewhat recent update, I've seen that page before where the dialog did not have that blue outline at the start.

Comment: It's because of the default browser selection on controls when they are on focus

Comment: i think the reason is one of these as what the doc said `Upon opening a dialog, focus is automatically moved to the first item that matches the following:

1. The first element within the dialog with the autofocus attribute
2. The first :tabbable element within the dialog's content
3. The first :tabbable element within the dialog's buttonpane
4. The dialog's close button
5. The dialog itself`

Comment: I try in firefox, and there seem to be working ok. First try was chrome

Comment: safari and opera started with blue border as well just tried it

Comment: [found this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dialog-close-button-is-focused-on-open) and it has a good reply check it :)

Comment: @guradio Perfect. You should copy the answer with include link to the source, just in case the link disapear. Also I can give you the credit

Comment: @guradio You copy the full answer from there ... But also Include a link giving the credit to the source. So you arent plagiarizing... But again if the link disapear the answer will still be here. That is the important part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ***@scott.gonzalez*** from [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dialog-close-button-is-focused-on-open)

> In rc5 and previous releases the logic was:
>       find the first tabbable element in the dialog and give it focus on
>       open.
>       In current SVN the logic is:
>       find the first tabbable element in the following order:
>       - content area
>       - button pane
>       - title bar
>       and give it focus on open.
>       This is done for accessibility to ensure that the dialog has focus
>       when opened. We may change the logic after doing some testing to
>       focus the actual dialog div if the close button is what would receive
>       focus.

Try this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    open: function() {
      $(this).parents('.ui-dialog').attr('tabindex', -1)[0].focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: yea i was gonna update the answer with the code you did it for me :)

Comment: Last thing regarding copy answers, just in case. If the correct answer is already in this site, you not create a new answer, just use the `DUPLICATED` function to link to that content. Unless you are using that content to create a specific new answer.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza noted :)

Answer (score 0):

By default focus an element of dialog box to make active or actionable dialog box (For Front Focus).

By Default it is :

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    open: function() {
      $(this).parents('.ui-dialog').attr('tabindex', -1)[0].focus();
    }
});
```

you can override it as for your requirment:

```
      $(this).parents('.ui-dialog').attr('tabindex', -1)[0].trigger( "focusout" );
```

Comment: I dont understand why you say that is the default. When I use the answer from guradio the problem was solve it.... so that wasnt the default.

Comment: its because to focusing on dialog box or to make dialog box active mode,or if you use Enter key then it from on dialog box first.